# How to generate k random variables numbers from a hypergeometric distribution?

Tags: r, random

I am trying to make my own function in order to generate `nn` random variables from a hypergeometric distribution. I know with `rhyper(nn,m,n,k)`, which is an R function, I can directly do it. However, I want to make my own function named `rHypg(nn,m,n,k)`. I have made the following function:

```
rHypg <- function(nn, m, n, k) {
  x <- seq(nn)
  for (i in 1:nn) {
    N = n
    M = m
    for (j in 1:k) {
      b <-
        sample(0:1,
               size = 1,
               prob = c(M / (M + N), N / (M + N)))
      if (b == 0) {
        M <- M - 1
        x[i] <- x[i] + 1
      } else if (b == 1) {
        N <- N - 1
      }
    }
  }
  return(x)
}
```

When I test my above function (`rHypg`) for some examples like `rHypg(10, 7, 8, 5)` and `rHypg(10,7, 3, 10)` I get below results in output:

```
rHypg(10, 7, 8, 5)
##  [1]  4  5  6  7  7  9  9 11 11 12
rHypg(10,7, 3, 10)
##  [1]  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
```

The above results are wrong because output random numbers must be <= `m`. I think I need to use `stop` somewhere inside my function to resolve this problem, but I don not know how (I think in order to my function generates `nn` random variables from a hypergeometric distribution, when `x[i]=m` it has to be stoped)!

Could you please help me to correct my code in order to generate correctly `nn` random variables from a hypergeometric distribution with parameters `nn`, `m`, `n` and `k`?

[[Hint: Explanations regarding hypergeometric distribution:

`nn`: number of observations.
`m`: the number of white balls in the urn.
`n`: the number of black balls in the urn.
`k`: the number of balls drawn from the urn, hence must be in 0,1,…, m+n.]]

Comment: I think you need to keep track of the original `m` and `n`, and reset them inside the `i` before the `j` loop begins. As-is, `m` keeps going down, down down, and when it is negative your `prob` argument to sample doesn't make sense. You also might divide by 0 when `m = -n`.

Comment: Rather than nested loops within one function, I would suggest writing a function that generates a single number from the hypergeometric dist, call it `rHYPG_1`. And then write a wrapper function `rHYPG` that calls `rHYPG_1` `n` times. It might make your code cleaner (and would have avoided this issue entirely).

Comment: A last little piece of advice - `c` is the name of perhaps the most commonly used R function. To avoid confusion, don't name a variable `c` unless you have a really good reason for it.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations @GregorThomas. I have tested your suggestions. I still see that error. Could you please write your own code?

Comment: I edited my question and my code